# ejabberd no such file or directory "p1_pgsql.app"

Tags: postgresql, xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying the authenticate with the `ODBC` authentication method. I have set up with the database like

```
createdb ejabberd
psql ejabberd < /path/to/pg.sql
createuser ejabberd
ALTER ROLE ejabberd WITH PASSWORD 'ejabberd';
```

and in the `ejabberd.yml` file, i just enable the odbc auth method and configured the pgsql settings like

```
auth_method: odbc
odbc_type: pgsql
odbc_server: localhost
odbc_database: ejabberd
odbc_username: ejabberd
odbc_password: ejabberd
```

When starting the ejabberd server I see the error:

```
jabberd:exit_or_halt:133 failed to start application 'p1_pgsql': {error,
                                         {"no such file or directory",
                                          "p1_pgsql.app"}}
```

Anyone help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not compile ejabberd with pgsql support (./configure --enable-pgsql) Please read the compilation options for more information: http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/#installing-ejabberd-from-source-code

If you did not build it yourself, you should download binary installer or packages from ProcessOne. They contains all the needed dependencies: https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/

Comment: Thanks Mickael. Found the answer at the github in the [same issue](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/655) which I have raise.